# Create Nomenclature and Abbreviation separately on Latex

Tags: acronyms, nomenclature

I have a thesis template, which allows me to add nomenclature. See below.

```
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\printnomenclature
```

I can change the name of the nomenclature with the command on the preamble (`\renewcommand{\nomname}{Notation}`), but I would like to create an abbreviation section apart from the nomenclature. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are nomenclature groups. To add these, you have to renew the nomgroup command. The setup that I currently use is the following:

```
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{\item[\Large\bfseries{Abbreviations}]}{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{B}{\vspace{15pt} \item[\Large\bfseries{Some other group}]}{}}%
}
```

This will create two distinct groups in your nomenclature with their own separate titles. Adding elements to these groups is done using the normal command with an additional group identifier:

```
\nomenclature[A]{e.g.}{exempli gratia}
```

Here, the group identifier `A` is provided which means that this entry will go into the abbreviations group. You can add as many groups as you want by adding additional definitions in `\renewcommand`.

If you want to have the abbreviations group on a completely different page, you can replace `\vspace{15pt}` by `\clearpage`. Whatever you type when redefining the `\nomgroup` command is executed at the start of a new group.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful explanation @Pascià